# Evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^a}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I should calculate this expression, with $a > 0$:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^a}.$$

But I am stuck at this equation for quite some time.
Its a indeterminate form but we are not yet allowed to use the L'Hôpital's rule.
We definded $x^a = e^{a\ln(a)}$.

I tried some things such as sandwich theorem, but it didnt work.
Overall I just have no idea how to solve this.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do think the limit is? And why? This is always a good starting point for computing a limit.

Comment: This has been asked a million times before on this site.

Comment: why is he in the second answer allowed to replace x^a with e^y?